# Ruid2 module configuration with Apache2.4

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04

I try to set up an Ubuntu 16.04 server with Apache2.4 running with the Ruid2 module.

`sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-ruid2 php7.0-cgi`

but when I run php scripts php code is not interpreted.
So what are the configuration steps regarding the ruid2 module, what are the files to edit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should work...

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-ruid2
a2enmod libapache2-mod-ruid2
```

...but I also found this answer that says it doesn't...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/769232/apache2-mod-ruid2-doesnt-work